# Color change in Line series chartview in qml

Tags: qml, lineseries

I want to change the color of my axes data in a line chart in QML, like the following example:

[image: ValueAxis titles]

Source code:

```
ChartView {
    title: "Rx4"
    backgroundColor: "black"
    legend.visible: false

    LineSeries {
        axisX: ValueAxis {
            min: 0
            max: 10
            titleText: "Frequency(Hz)"
            gridVisible: false
            color:"white"
        }

        axisY: ValueAxis {
            min: 0
            max: 10
            titleText: "Power(dBm)"
            color:"white"
            gridVisible: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this `titleBrush: Qt.rgba(1,0,0,1)`. [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractaxis.html#titleBrush-prop)

Comment: @smr Thanks, Its working. For white color, what values I need to give.I donot find in the docs. Kindly help

Comment: It's an RGBA color, with parameters that should be in the range of 0 to 1, so for a white color, you should use `Qt.rgba(1,1,1,1)`.